# Loop Elements in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run a loop over a few elements in JQuery.  Before anyone says it, I do not need `.each()`.  I am trying to run through the elements as a genuine loop- once a successful iteration runs, the loop will break and prevent the same action being done on other elements.  I looked briefly at the straight JavaScript version, with the `.getElement...` methods, but it is my understanding that this won't satisfy my other requirement- the list of elements to be iterated over is created via a partial-string JQuery identifier:

```
rows = $('tr[id^="am_assetRow_' + parentAsset.replace(/ /, "_") + '_' + type + '"]');
```

Does anyone know of anything that might help me get this working?

**EDIT:**  Just a bit more information on the application: I am checking to see if a value can be inserted into an existing row of a table, and if not, creating a new row and inserting it there.  Thus, I need the loop to exit if a suitable fit is found, and after the loop terminates, I need to know whether it terminated in success (placing the value) or failure (no available locations- time to create a new row).

Comment: If you want to break from the loop in `each`, simply return false.

Comment: It is difficult to say without the context in which you want to loop

Comment: What is it you're trying to *do*, and how do you (expect to) assess 'success' (or 'failure')?

Answer (score 5):

In jquery, if you want a `$.each()` loop to end immediately, just `return false` from the function call.

Comment: *Before anyone says it, I do not need .each()*

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan If I understand the question correctly, the asker is incorrect in that assertion.

Comment: @JasonP than the OP should take the consequences ;) hehe

Comment: I was not aware you could do this- thanks.  Is there any way to predict in what order the elements will be processed?

Comment: Also, will the returned value be propagated?  I need to know if ANY of the loops succeeded afterwards.  For more on the application, see above.

Answer (score 1):

Do do a normal loop without using `each()` but still using jquery to select the items based on  partial string etc...

```
rows = $('tr[id^="am_assetRow_' + parentAsset.replace(/ /, "_") + '_' + type + '"]');
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
  rows[i];    // The raw element at this index.
  $(rows[i]); // jquery collection for this one element.
  if (someCondition) {
    break; // Break the loop early.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks- this is just what I am looking for.  Is there any way to predict in which order the elements will be processed?

Comment: It depends on how jquery finds and puts them into their collection, in any case, I would not expect any particular order to be reliable.  Best way to go is probably use jquery `.map()` to convert the collection into an array and then use `array.sort()` to sort them how you want, then iterate through that new array.